# create JavaScript Array w/ data from object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array of objects similar to this

```
var employees = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName": "Jones"}
];
```

How can I get the Array of first names from this object without using a loop?

```
employees.firstName
```

Is it possible to work without using employeed[0] and get the list of first name array ??

Answer (score 3):

```
var firstNames = employees.map(function(emp){return emp.firstName});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `underscore.js`, you can do it like this :

```
var firstNames = _.map(employees, _.property('firstName'));
```

Otherwise, you can use ES5 `map`:

```
var firstNames = employees.map(function(employee){return employee.firstName;});
```

Comment: If you have Underscore, you can just use `pluck`:  `_.pluck(employees, 'firstName')`.